# Moving Java Comparator logic out of entity?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, comparator

I currently have a java `Entities`: `Cat` and `Kitten`

Below is the Cat entity that contains the current `comparator` logic to order the Cat entities by which cat has the oldest Kitten

```
public class Cat implements Comparable<Cat>
{

    //other fields and methods

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cat",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Kitten> kittenList= new ArrayList<Kitten>();

     public DateTime getOldestBornValueForKittenInList(){

        return kittenList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Kitten::getBorn))
                .get().getBorn();
    }

    public int compareTo(Cat c) {

        //fist compare on the oldest Created DateTime Value
        int i = getOldestBornValueForKittenInList().compareTo(c.getOldestBornValueForKittenInList());
        if (i != 0){
            return i;
        }

    }

}
```

I **no longer** want my Cat Entity to implement the `comparable` interface. Can I call the comparator in my application instead?

I.e. if I wanted an `ordered Map` of cats and their list of kittens, with the cat with the oldest kitten being the first entry in the map:

```
Map<Cat, List<Kitten>> mapOfCatsAndKittens = new HashMap<Cat, List<Kitten>>();
```

Comment: In general, having logic in an entity class is bad practice, have a service with the entity autowired to apply your logic

Comment: Why not `TreeMap`? It is designed to take a `comparator`.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg can you give example of the service that I could replace the entity logic with?

Comment: @Tirath thanks, please give example of how I can add a comparator to a treemap?

Comment: I never said add. Anyways, you can look at TreeMap here -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html. Check out the constructors. You can pass in your `comparator` implementation.

Comment: Another side note: When you implement `Comparable` (i.e. the `compareTo` method), you should make sure that it is *consistent with equals* as described in the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) documentation.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg not so sure about that... Have you heard about [anemic  domain model anti-pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your code contains several unnecessary duplications. In

```
public DateTime getOldestBornValueForKittenInList() {
    return kittenList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Kitten::getBorn)).get().getBorn();
}
```

you let the comparator fetch the property `getBorn` despite the fact that this is the only property you are interested in. So you can simplify the operation to

```
public DateTime getOldestBornValueForKittenInList() {
    return kittenList.stream().map(Kitten::getBorn).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
}
```

By mapping to the property first, you get a stream of `DateTime` elements which you can compare naturally, without having to re-fetch the property on each comparison. An the result is already the minimum `DateTime`.

Keep in mind that in either case, the operation fails if the list is empty.

But the `Comparator.comparing` factory still has its place. Right when you want to compare `Cat` objects by a property:

```
Comparator<Cat> oldestKitten=Comparator.comparing(Cat::getOldestBornValueForKittenInList);
```

You can use such a comparator to create a map, sorted by that property

```
Map<Cat, List<Kitten>> mapOfCatsAndKittens = new TreeMap<>(oldestKitten);
```

or to sort a list of `Cat`s:

```
List<Cat> list= … ; // should be a mutable list implementation, e.g. ArrayList
// perhaps add (some more) Cats
list.sort(oldestKitten);
```

Comment: thanks, Can I also use multiple clauses in the comparator?, i.e. if I wanted to firstly check for the oldestBornValue of the kitten, then also check for another clause? Incase the first 2 are equal?

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(Cat::firstProperty).thenComparing(Cat::nextProperty)`

Comment: Thanks, so the first key in this Treemap will be the Cat with the oldest kitten first, the 2nd key will be the Cat with 2nd oldest kitten and so on?

Comment: If cat #1 has the oldest kitten and the second oldest kitten, the second value in the map will be the cat with the third oldest kitten. Is that ok?